# Want to use ECC but am clueless

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, pgp

First off, I'm not an experienced cryptography or computer person, please bear with me. I have some basic experiences with PGP software though (not much of a redemption huh?). I have some data that I'd like to protect with ECC encryption, but I can't for the life of me find a tool or anything that can use ECC.

I'm not a computer programmer or anything. I just need a tool that I can use to encrypt my stuff with ECC. I'd be willing to pay for a software if anybody knows of one, but free is always best.

Comment: This is off-topic as it as about security software recommendation rather than actual cryptography. But I think you should really rethink your problem - generally end users should not concern themselves with which algorithms are being used to secure their data, just that it is, so a general purpose tool will probably serve you better (and it may or may not use elliptic curve technology), otherwise you are probably only going to find hobby, proof-of-concept tools that are probably flawed and insecure...

Comment: Sorry, this i'm new here. Is there somewhere else I should post it?

Comment: @zakshaks, Help Center [says](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "If your question is about usage of a specific cryptographic software (not its cryptographic internals), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is the right site."

Comment: @zakshaks I can migrate the question to Super User if you would like.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: `I'd be willing to pay for a software if anybody knows of one, but free is always best.` – Just an idea… but have you thought about asking at **[SoftwareRecomendations.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)**? From my point of view, that would be the perfect place for you to get some software recommendations. ;)

Comment: @e-sushi I am just new to this website, so I didn't know where I should put it, thanks for the advise.